# Spring data save в со связью Many to Many

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

У меня есть две сущности `User` `Role` со связей `Many to Many`,я использую метод `save`, он делает вот такой запрос, но мне не нужно, что бы он создавал новую роль, а нужно, что бы извлекал `id`  из таблицы `role` вставлял в связную таблицу `id` этой `role` и связывал ее `user_id` как это сделать? Спасибо большое. Извините за глупый вопрос.

**Запрос при save**

```
  *user.insert into users (first_name, last_name, password, state, username, id)
      values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  Hibernate: insert into role (role_name, id) values (?, ?)*
```

**User**

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;
        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;
        @Column(name = "state")
        private Boolean state;
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = Role.class)
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns =
        @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private Set<Role> roles;



        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }


        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Boolean getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(Boolean state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
    }
```

**Role**

```
@Entity
        @Table(name = "role")
        public class Role implements Serializable {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private Long id;
            @Column(name = "role_name")
            private String roleName;
            @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity = User.class)
            private Set<User> users;

            public Set<User> getUsers() {
                return users;
            }

            public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
                this.users = users;
            }

            public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public long getId() {
                return id;
            }


            public String getRoleName() {
                return roleName;
            }

            public Role setRoleName(String roleName) {
                this.roleName = roleName;
                return this;
            }
        }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository("UserRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM  User u WHERE  u.username=:username")
    User getUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);


}
```

**UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>() {{
            add(new Role().setRoleName("USER"));
        }});
        user.setState(true);
        userRepository.save(user);


    }
}
```

Comment: Так вы же сами в методе `addUser` создаёте новую роль. Выбирайте и устанавливайте существующую роль.

Comment: Хм,я думал,что будет автоматически искать эту роль в таблице и сам ее  вытаскивать и связывать,то есть мне нужно самому написать запрос на выборку этой id_role и вставку в связную таблицу?

Comment: @MaximBogunenko Если бы ключ был `roleName`, то можно было бы так делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Роль я бы заменил на `enum` и упростил себе жизнь. Останется только одна сущность `User`. Примерно так:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String name, Role... roles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roles.addAll(Arrays.asList(roles));
    }

    //...
}

public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    USER, ADMIN

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

В итоге, сохранение юзера будет выглядеть так:

```
User user = userRepository.save(new User("user", USER));
```

Рабочий [пример](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example6).

Позволю пару советов...

1. <strike>Отношение Юзер-Роль никак не ManyToMany. Это OneToMany (один юзер может иметь много ролей). Пример ManyToMany - это Школьники-Кружки: Школьник может посещать несколько школьных кружков. И каждый кружок посещает несколько школьников.</strike>
2. Роль вообще ничего не знает про юзеров, поэтому в ней не стоит иметь ссылку на юзера.
3. У тебя роль записывается вместе с юзером, потому что установлен Cascade=All. В этом случае ВСЕ операции с верхней сущностью каскадно выполняются и с подчиненной. Каскад здесь совсем лишний, т.к. роль не зависит от юзера.

Очень рекомендую почитать этот [материал](https://habrahabr.ru/post/271115/).

Comment: Это не всегда возможно. Например, Spring Security ожидает, что в базе будет отдельная таблица для ролей.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Возможно )) Все зависит от того как мы реализуем `UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил в ответе имплементацию `GrantedAuthority` для `Role`.

Comment: Вы были правы насчет,что cascade all тут точно лишний,как только я его убрал,save заработал как нужно,а насчет many to many например автор это го туториала делает так http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-jpa2-hibernate-many-to-many-example/

Comment: @User Рад, что помог (только не забудь проголосовать...). В статье автор не совсем подходящий пример использовал, отношение User-Profile - это скорее OneToOne.

Comment: @Cepr0 Почему Юзер-Роль не @ManyToMany? Есть роль 'ROLE_MODERATOR' и многие пользователи могут ее иметь. Тут https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration используется ManyToMany.

Comment: @parsecer Согласен. Давно это было. Вероятно, когда это писал, то думал про энамы.. )

Comment: @Cepr0 Спасибо за ответ. Мне это встречалось в нескольких туториалах и тольк единичные туториалы (включая baeldung) используют `@ManyToMany` для пользователей и ролей. Меня это мучало.

Comment: @parsecer да, для таких простых вещей использовать лишние таблицы - это накладно. Если используешь постгрес или мускуль, имеет смысл сейчас выносить такое в [json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326794/5380322), ИМХО...